# Macbook Pro 11,2 - no sound with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: sound, 13.10, macbook

The sound hardware works.  I get the ding during boot up and if I boot to Mac OS, sound works.

When I boot to Ubuntu 13.10, most everything works except there's no sound.

The headphone jack-light is red.  The on-screen visuals seem to think the sound is turned up.  I tried alsa's mixer control and it thinks sound is on.  But nothing comes out of speakers or headphones (when they're plugged in).

This is a relatively new 11,2 Macbook Pro 15" with Retina display.

Comment: Have you tried looking for drivers in system settings? Additionally, take a snapshot of your window under the sound panel.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 13.10 only (later versions fix the issue), there are instructions on [the Ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro11-1/Saucy), quoted below:

---

> Speakers (13.10 only)
>
> Skip this section for 14.04.
>
> For 13.10, the speakers have no sound at boot and after resume from suspend. I fixed these by setting GPIO flags at boot and after resume. First, we need the `alsa-tools` package
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install alsa-tools
> ```
>
> To make the speakers work after boot:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/rc.local
> ```
>
> to add the following command before `exit 0`
>
> ```
> hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x1 set_gpio_data 1
> ```
>
> To make the speakers work after resume, I edited `/etc/pm/sleep.d/99_myfix` that I created above
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_myfix
> ```
>
> to add the following before `;;`
>
> ```
> hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x1 set_gpio_mask 1
> sleep 1
> hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x1 set_gpio_direction 1
> sleep 1
> hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x1 set_gpio_data 1
> ```
>
> The sleep commands are here because without them the flags are not all set sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

@doctororange your instruction fixes the same issue on my Ubuntu 13.10 on Macbook Pro 12 Retina

```
hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x1 set_gpio_data 1
```

Thanks :-)